# Using User-Downloaded DLLs In Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: dll, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

**Short question:**

Does the Windows Store allow applications that obtain DLLs or other low-level resources not packaged at compile time? Is there a requirement either by Windows Phone or Microsoft that requires DLLs to be signed? If so, can I use a DLL in my application that is signed by another developer?

**Why I'm asking/explanation:**
I'm working an an application for Android that allows users to download extensions (like themes), and I'd like to port this to Windows Phone.


I have determined that it's not possible for my app to utilize libraries or other resources of other applications downloaded from the Windows Store. (Please correct me if this is not always the case)


The workaround I'm considering is an in-app download center for other resources specific to this application. I'm wondering if a downloads for this app, specifically DLLs, can be used in my application. These DLLs would be developed by 3rd party developers, so I see that signing might be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The store specifically prohibits any additions / modifications after the app has been purchased. So although it may technically be possible, they won't certify it.

This makes sense if you think about certification . If they would allow this, it would make certification a moot point, since you would just publish a basic app, and afterwards side-load the uncertified part.